# why the bootstrap5 modal hide did not work

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Today I want to hide the bootstrap5  `"bootstrap": "v5.3.1"` madal in typescript function, I just get the modal element and invoke the hide function but it seems did not work. The modal did not hide as expect, this is the minimal reproduce code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const handleModal = (show: boolean, modalId: string) => {
    let modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    if (modal) {
      var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modal);
      show ? myModal.show() : myModal.hide();

      myModal.hide();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => { handleModal(true, "deleteFileModal") }}>show</button>
      <div>
        <div className="modal fade" id="deleteFileModal" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Title</h5>
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" >Confirm</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in the last I just invoke the modal hide, the modal did not hide finnaly. Am I misssing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? In my project, I use the hide like this:

```
const handleOk = () => {
        let params = {
            name: createFileName,
            project_id: pid,
            parent: pid,
            file_type: 1
        };
        addFile(params).then((resp) => {
            if (ResponseHandler.responseSuccess(resp)) {
                handleModal(false,"createFileModal");
                getFileList(pid?.toString());
            }
        });
    };
```

and define the modal function like this:

```
 const handleModal = (show: boolean, modalId: string) => {
        let modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
        if (modal) {
            var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modal);
            show ? myModal.show() : myModal.hide();
        }
    }
```

did not close the modal success.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your handleModal function that should help address these issues:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

const App: React.FC = () => {
const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const myModalRef = useRef<bootstrap.Modal | null>(null);

const handleModal = (show: boolean) => {
if (modalRef.current) {
  if (!myModalRef.current) {
    myModalRef.current = new bootstrap.Modal(modalRef.current);
  }

  if (show) {
    myModalRef.current.show();
  } else {
    myModalRef.current.hide();
  }
}
};

useEffect(() => {
// Clean up modal instance when component unmounts
return () => {
  if (myModalRef.current) {
    myModalRef.current.dispose();
    myModalRef.current = null;
  }
};
}, []);

return (
<div>
  <button onClick={() => handleModal(true)}>Show</button>
  <button onClick={() => handleModal(false)}>Hide</button>
  <div>
    <div className="modal fade" ref={modalRef} id="deleteFileModal" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Title</h5>
            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            Modal content goes here...
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
);
}

 export default App;
```

I've used the useRef hook to store a reference to the modal element.
The useEffect hook is used to clean up the modal instance when the component unmounts.
We're using bootstrap.Modal.getInstance to get the existing instance of the modal and call dispose on it for proper cleanup.

Comment: It may not this issue, in my project, I use it like this did not work. I invoke the hide when http response still could not close the show modal. not in one place. @Mohammed Ali

Comment: In your handleModal function, you are calling myModal.hide(); twice. You should remove the extra call to myModal.hide();  @Dolphin

Comment: Since you are dynamically showing and hiding the modal, it's important to ensure proper initialization and cleanup to prevent any unexpected behavior. like adding useRef hook to store a reference to the modal element. and useEffect to clean up the modal instance when the component unmounts. @Dolphin

Comment: seems the hide only can trigger in events.

Comment: Have you tried the above edited answer? @Dolphin

Comment: I have tried, the show modal works, but dit not contain the hide logic.

Comment: I've updated the answer again, hope you solve it this time.